# C# SQL Insert statement - if first column has text insert into the next

Tags: c#, sql, sql-insert

I have built an RFID Race Timing system and all is functioning well but now I need to either insert or update the tblMovement entry.

When inserting I must use tagID, movementDate, checkDate. movementDate is the actual tag read time. checkDate is for my anti collision functionality. When inserting it must place the movementDate into @Lap1.

When updating I must locate the tagID and check if @Lap1, @Lap2, @Lap3, @Lap4 or @Lap5 have data. If @Lap3 has data then I must insert into @Lap4 etc.

My SQL search query which locates the tagID is functioning fine and it either Updates or Inserts based on the results. My biggest challenge is scanning each column to see which has data. I have source code but its too much for this window.....

Comment: Are you looking for an All-SQL statement or you want to fetch the existing record and then have this logic in C#?

Comment: I assume you don't want to normalise your table for some reason and happy with he fact that you can have only 5 laps recorded

Comment: I just want to fetch the existing record (if it exists) and apply the logic in C#. What are the challenges with normalising the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having 5 lap times, it would be good to break this out into a normalized structure.  That would mean having a `tblMovementLaps` table, with the following structure.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblMovementLaps(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [TagId] INT NOT NULL,
    [MovementDate] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [CheckDate] DATETIME NOT NULL
)
```

You would insert a new record into `tblMovement` at the start of each race, and a new record into `tblMovementLap` every time you were recording a new lap.  Then you would join between the two to review a race, with:

```
SELECT *
FROM [tblMovement] TM
    JOIN [tblMovementLaps] TML
    ON TM.[TagId] = TML.[Id]
ORDER BY TML.[Id] ASC
```

A big benefit of doing things this way - it lets you record races of infinite lap counts without breaking your structure or expanding your movement table into more and more columns.  Also it lets you keep space in the movement table available for information that is truly unique to each race (the basis of normalization), like the racer ID, race date, etc.

All that said, if you REALLY wanted to continue to support your current structure, you could add a `[CurrentLap]` field to `TblMovement`.  Always insert your lap time to that field.  Set up an UPDATE trigger on your table to move that value into one of the @lap fields based on which are populated

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the help. I will test this afternoon and advise